Given a set of integers, and the number of summations find the resulting frequencies
Given a set $X = \{x_1,x_2,...x_m\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ and the number of allowed addends $N$. How can I find the frequency of every possible sum?

Example: $X = \{-1, 2\}$ and $N=3$ then every possible sum would be:
\begin{align}
-1-1-1 &=-3 \\
-1-1+2 &= 0 \\
-1+2-1 &= 0 \\
-1+2+2 &= 3 \\
+2-1-1 &= 0 \\
+2-1+2 &= 3 \\
+2+2-1 &= 3 \\
+2+2+2 &= 6 \\
\end{align}
And the resulting frequency list from the smallest possible value to the maximum possible value$(\{-3, -2, ... 5, 6\})$ would be: $\{1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1\}$

Is there a better way than just to do it by brute force? I coded it up and even for small $N$ and $|X|$ it takes way too long.
If it wasn't for the values with frequency $0$, we would get a multinominal distribution, so the multinominal coefficient would come to my mind. However we would still not know what sum corresponds to the value we get out.

It is not clear to me why the multinomial or generating function approach is not sufficient. We obtain according to your example
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(x^{-1}+x^2\right)^3=x^{-3}+3x^0+3x^3+x^6}
\end{align*}
where the exponent of the term $x^n$ indicates the sum and the coefficient of $x^n$ the number of occurrences. The frequency list can derived easily from this representation.

The overall complexity doesn't change here a lot compared to the brute force OP mentioned.

@EnEm Assuming you represent the polynomial as an array of coefficients of length $d+1$ (where $d=\max(x_1,\dots,x_m)-\min(x_1,\dots,x_m)$), and you use exponentiation by squaring and FFT convolution, then the runtime of Markus's method is $O(d\cdot n\cdot \log(dn))$. This is faster than the method in my answer, which is $O(d\cdot m\cdot n^2)$.

Oh yeah, sorry about that. Can you edit this in your post as well? One correction: when you square the polynomial, its array of coefficients becomes of size $2d+1$. In general $T(n) = T(n/2) + \mathcal{O}(nd \log nd)$ which gives us $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(nd \log nd)$

Oh I saw the edit now, ignore my analysis in the last comment

An advantage of the generating function approach is that it makes it more obvious when simplifications occur. For instance, in the present case one can write $(x^{-1}+x^2)^3=x^{-3}(1+x^3)^3$. Hence the only possible sums are multiples of three. (Of course, this also follows from $-2=1$ mod 3.)

Here is a more efficient algorithm. Given a list of integers $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ and a positive integer $n$, this algorithm will output an associative array, whose keys are the possible $n$-fold sums of the lists $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$, and whose values are the number of times that sum occurs.
The algorithm is recursive. The base case is $n=1$, in which case you just output the associate array whose keys are $x_i$ $(i\in \{1,\dots,n\})$, and each value associated to $x_i$ is the number of times that $x_i$ appears in $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$.
Next, assume that $n>1$. The algorithm starts by recursively computing the associative array of $(n-1)$-fold sums. Call this array $A_{n-1}$; for each possible $(n-1)$-fold sum $s$, we use $A_{n-1}[s]$ to denote the number of ways to attain the sum $s$ using $n-1$ elements of $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$. The goal is to compute the next array, $A_n$.

Initialize an empty array $A_n$.
For each key $s$ of $A_{n-1}$:

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$:

If the key $s+x_i$ is not present in $A_n$, set $A_n[s+x_i]=0$
Increment the value $A_n[s+x_i]$.





This algorithm is more efficient than brute force in the case that the input list is not too spread out. Specifically, let $d=\max(x_1,\dots,x_m)-\min(x_1,\dots,x_m)$. I claim my algorithm has runtime $O(d\cdot m\cdot n^2)$. Indeed, the time it takes to compute $A_n$ from $A_{n-1}$ is equal to $m$ times the number of distinct sums for $A_{n-1}$, and by induction, you can prove for each $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ that $A_{k}$ has at most $k\cdot d\le n\cdot d$ distinct sums.
